# What is this abbreviation CT in female reproductive system

Tags: human-biology, homework, embryology

I have this sentence in my notes

> Ovary is surrounded by tunica albuginea and the cortex keeps the primordial follicles. The medulla containing CT and blood vessels develop from mesonephros.

I have these words in my mind about CT

- tunica
- cyto- (maybe cytotrophoblast)
- corona (no other than corona radiata so not)

**What can CT be here?**

Comment: Homework question and too easy. Please, close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think CT is an abbreviation for **connective tissue**. Some examples of its use in that fashion:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connective_tissue

https://web.archive.org/web/20151024041339/http://www.vetmed.vt.edu/education/curriculum/vm8054/Labs/Lab5/Lab5.htm

http://www.pitt.edu/~sshostak/biosci1450/hislec03.html

Comment: I found this as well, and it is a fact about the ovaries.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer! Yes, it makes sense.